# How to identify save browser username and password in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a requirement to disable login button when either username or password is null.

Please find code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input').on('keyup  blur mouseenter', function(e) {


       if($("#userName").val().length!==0 && $.trim($('#userName').val()) !== '' && $("#password").val().length!==0 && $.trim($('#password').val())!== ''){

            $('#submitLogin').attr('disabled',false);
        }
    });
});
```

Please find submit input below in jsp page:

```
 <input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" id ="submitLogin"value="Login" disabled="true" ></div>
```

I manage to do it in jquery as shown above,but my issue is with saved username and password by the browser.

That is  when user first login application browser asked user to save username and password and user click yes.

So once username/password is saved the next time the user open the login page the username and password is already filled but the login button is still disabled.

It is disable because even if the input username/password is already filled in, when it calls the jquery method the value for both input text is null.

However when the user click again then the username and password is initialised and submitLogin is enabled.

Any idea how i can get the value of the saved username and password when the page load first time so I can enable the login input?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What happens if you make the anonymous function a named function, and call that in the `document.ready()`? Meaning you run the function when the values change like you do now, and once at the start of the page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$.removeAttr()`, `$.change()` and use input `input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" id="submitLogin" value="Login">` like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($("#userName").val().length !== 0 && $.trim($('#userName').val()) !== '' && $("#password").val().length !== 0 && $.trim($('#password').val()) !== '') {

    $('#submitLogin').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('#submitLogin').attr('disabled', "");
  }

  $('input').on('change keyup  blur mouseenter ', function(e) {


    if ($("#userName").val().length !== 0 && $.trim($('#userName').val()) !== '' && $("#password").val().length !== 0 && $.trim($('#password').val()) !== '') {

      $('#submitLogin').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $('#submitLogin').attr('disabled', "");
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='userName' />
<input type="password" id="password"/>
<input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" id="submitLogin" value="Login">
```

Comment: Hi i have added $.removeAttr() and on load it is working, however when the user login and and click log out which redirect to the login page although username and password is filled the submit button is disable,any tips pls?

Comment: Great working fine and next time I WILL not define the disable in hmtl but will let jquery handle it instead

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('input').on('keyup blur mouseenter', function(e) {

            if($.trim($('#userName').val()) && $.trim($('#password').val())){

                $('#submitLogin').prop('disabled',false);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="userName">
<input id="password">
<input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" id ="submitLogin"value="Login" disabled="disabled" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: attr and prop are both ok, but I suggest prop to set disabled.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for answering on a question. Keep in mind that a good answer contains an explanation on what the OP is supposed to do. This helps the OP and future members looking for an answer on a simular issue